# Replace part of string with variable, but with complicated delimiters

Tags: php, regex

I know that I can use str_replace to replace certain things quite easily in a string. But I'm completely stuck with how to do it when I cannot find a really easy delimiter for the content.

I have strings which can have links anywhere in them, e.g

```
$tweet = "Testing a tweet with a link https://t.co/h4C0aobVnK in the middle";
```

or

```
$tweet = "Testing a tweet with a link: https://t.co/dgg0eA3uIt";
```

I have a variable `$embedded_link` which contains a prettified `<a>` tag ready to go. E.g

```
<a href="https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only" target="_blank">dev.twitter.com/oauth/applicat…</a>
```

I need to replace the link, which always starts with `https://` and is defined by ending when there is a next space, and replace it with `$embedded_url`

So this:

```
$tweet = "Testing a tweet with a link https://t.co/h4C0aobVnK in the middle";
```

Becomes this:

```
$tweet = "Testing a tweet with a link <a href="https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only" target="_blank">dev.twitter.com/oauth/applicat…</a> in the middle";
```

How would you go about this? I was thinking of using `https://` and a `space` as the delimiters, but it's possible for there to be no space at the end of the string.

Comment: Your own description is pretty clear: `https://\S+` (reads: "https:// and some non-spaces").

Comment: This should work for you: http://regex101.com/r/xB8lP2/1

Comment: `$tweet = preg_replace('~https://\S+~', $embedded_url, $tweet);`

Comment: If you're going with a generic regex as @georg suggests, I'd also advise on `\bhttps?://\S+(?<![,.])` for excluding a few common flow-text punctuation symbols (sample `Tweet http://example.com/, which I like`).

Comment: @anubhava good answer. Can you add this as a q so I can mark it correct?

Comment: Why are you replacing all links with a constant link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from your examples following should work for you:

```
$tweet = preg_replace('~\bhttps://\S+~', $embedded_url, $tweet);
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xB8lP2/1)

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use strstr for find string started with https://

```
$url = strstr($str, "https://");
```

then use strpos for find end. If found space then substr string by this length. Else variable already contains url.

```
$pos = strpos($url, " ");
if ($pos > 0) {
  $url = substr($url, 0, $pos)
}
```

Comment: Can you show how this would be used to replace the string?

Comment: While this of course amounts to the same result, manual string lookups are really just a more long-winded and less maintainable workaround to a regex oneliner.